# How to start 2660 port in IIS for Tridion Core Service connection using netTcp

Tags: tridion, tridion-core-services

**I am trying to connect to Tridion using core service script, here is my code:**

```
public static SessionAwareCoreServiceClient Client;


Client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("netTcp_2011");
Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
```

**web.Config has following:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- Default/example WCF settings for Core Service. These settings should be copied into the host application's configuration file. -->
    <bindings>
      <!-- Default Core Service binding settings are provided here. These can be used as a starting point for further customizations. -->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760"/>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="Basic" -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="streamDownload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="Basic" -->
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="streamUpload_basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedRequest" messageEncoding="Mtom" receiveTimeout="00:15:00">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcp" transactionFlow="true" transactionProtocol="WSAtomicTransaction11" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="streamDownload_netTcp" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedResponse" sendTimeout="00:20:00"/>
        <binding name="streamUpload_netTcp" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedRequest" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"/>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>     
      <!--Dev 2013   -->
      <endpoint name="netTcp_2011" address="net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService"/>
      <endpoint name="streamDownload_netTcp_2011" address="net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/streamDownload_netTcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamDownload_netTcp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamDownload"/>
      <endpoint name="streamUpload_netTcp_2011" address="net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/streamUpload_netTcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamUpload_netTcp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.IStreamUpload"/>
      <!--  -->

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Still I get this Error:**

```
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0520000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it localhost:2660.
```

**Note:** localhost can also be an IP of a CMS instance.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it listening on that port already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so Over the time I educated myself and can clearly say that the error `target machine actively refused it localhost:2660` clearly says that the port is not open for you to use.

**So do these two things to be sure:**

1. Make sure you have allowed net.tcp in IIS
2. And the port 2660 open in the windows firewall?

   run a `netstat -tan` to see whether anything is running on 2660, if not then you can not access it.

Also If you are running your code form local system or from another server, in case `netTcp` is not working, try to use `wsHttp` or `BasicHttp` (provided you have these bindings in your server core service's web.config)

Answer (score 1):

The Core Service runs as a Windows Service, not from IIS.  Open Windows Services and make sure that the Tridion Content Manager Service Host is running.